# Get the First & Last ListItem in Sharepoint List

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

On a `pageLoad` event I want to go to two different SharePoint Lists and get the first ListItem from one list and an the last ListItem in another. I don't know any of the ListItem ID's so I guess this needs to be done through the list index - just not sure how to implement this. Having got a handle on the List can someone advise (using c#) the best way to get the first and last items for the scenario outlined above?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The condition "first item" and "last item" is not very clear. Assuming you want to retrieve the first and the latest **created** item. Important to note is that retrieving items via the index of the `SPListItemCollection` can be slow for large lists since accessing `SPList.Items` returns all items of the list. That's why I suggest using a CAML query:

```
SPList list = // some list;
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.RowLimit = 1;
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy>";

return list.GetItems(query).Cast<SPListItem>().FirstOrDefault();
```

For the "last item" you have to reverse the ordering:

```
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>
```

If you want to get the last and the first item based on another condition you just have to change the order by field.

**Update:**
<s>Even better would be to order by the `ID` field. With that you could achieve the same result.</s>
Not only better, the created field could have been changed through code as pointed out by @Kobi.

Comment: Very nice. I would also recommend using the ID, the "created" date can be set by code. Also, if the lists are small, I'm not sure I would bother with the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to get the last itemID

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList List = web.Lists[ListName];

            int itemId = List.Items[List.ItemCount - 1].ID;
```

Regards!

Comment: This worked great for me.  I needed to perform some operations on a sorted SPListCollection, and I needed a value from the last item before I stepped over them all.  This allowed me to do it without writing an extra CAML query.  Thanks!

Comment: How About Removed Items Ids ??!

Comment: Down voted cause it's just guessing the last item ID.