# Document Upload into sharepoint using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a form which has a formview. i want to include a fileupload control to upload files into a sharepoint repository and save the uploaded files as ID_1,ID_2 etc. I am new to asp.net. I need help on how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can upload file to sharepoint using Client object model :

```
public void UploadFileToSharePoint(string filePath)
{
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("yoursite");
        Web web = context.Web;

        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
        newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        newFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("LibName");
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);

        context.Load(uploadFile);

        context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

After you can update the listitem with your required ID or you can attach a item updating event handler to update the Title of your file.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static void UploadBtn_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {  
   using (SPSite osite = new SPSite("URL"))
   {
    using (SPWeb oWeb = osite.OpenWeb())
    {
    oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPList list = oWeb.TryGetList("ListName");
    SPListItem item = list.AddItem();
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(UploadBtn.FileName, FileMode.Open) ;
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
    stream.Close();

    //read Last item ID here refer my 2nd link bellow

    item.Attachments.Add("ID_1.doc", byteArray);
    item["Title"] = TextBox1.Text;
    item.Update();
    oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
   }
  }
}
```

One more way to upload
1)http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addattachment.aspx

2)[Get the First & Last ListItem in Sharepoint List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726557/get-the-first-last-listitem-in-sharepoint-list)